# Converting IF condition to a mathematical equation

Tags: functions, computer-science

I am trying the formulate if conditions.

i=1...10
p=1...5
j=1...50
k=1...7

```
C_ijpk=b_ik+LC_ik+CC_ik ∀ijt k∈ {1,2,3}
```

I have three different LC_ik values and also two different coefficient CC_ik. in my formula, these coefficients connection with age_ijpk and J_i.

İf age is changing LC_ik will change. And if the scenario(j) is changing CC_ik will change.

>

how can I convert an IF condition to a mathematical equation?

```
C_ijpk= b_ik+LC_ik (if ageijpk <=60) or LC_ik (if ageijpk >60 and <=140) or LC_ik (if ageijpk >140)+CC_ik  (if Ji < 100 or CC_ik (if Ji = 100).
```

AIMMs code.

```
if AgeAft(i,j,t)<=60 then
bikf(i)+LCik1(i)
elseif  AgeAft(i,j,t)>60 and AgeAft(i,j,t)<=140 then
bikf(i)+LCik2(i)
elseif AgeAft(i,j,t)>140 then
bikf(i)+LCik3(i)
endif;
```

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on what you want to do next. As an example,
$$y(x) = \begin{cases}a \mbox{ if } x\ge c, \\ b \mbox{ if }x<c \end{cases}$$
can be imlemented as
$$
y(x) = a\, \frac{1 + \mathrm{sgn}(x-c)}{2} + b\,\frac{1 - \mathrm{sgn}(x-c)}{2},
$$
where $\mathrm{sgn}$ is the sign function defined at zero as $\mathrm{sgn}(0)=1$. Note that this definition of $\mathrm{sgn}$ also implicitly involves IF.